# Bad Exception on dealloc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I having a problem with a Bad Exception that I could not locate at first, but now have it pinned down on a `[super dealloc];`, but I have no idea why this happens.

Here is my code :

**EditingViewController.h**

```
@interface EditingViewController : UIViewController 
{

    NSManagedObject *editedObject;
    NSString *editedFieldKey;
    NSString *editedFieldName;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *editedObject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *editedFieldKey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *editedFieldName;


- (IBAction)cancel;
- (IBAction)save;

@end
```

**EditingViewController.m**

```
#import "EditingViewController.h"

@implementation EditingViewController

@synthesize editedObject, editedFieldKey, editedFieldName;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(editedFieldName, nil);

    // Configure the save and cancel buttons.
    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(save)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
    [saveButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
    [cancelButton release];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (IBAction)save 
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)cancel
{
    // Don't pass current value to the edited object, just pop.
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [editedObject release];
    [editedFieldKey release];
    [editedFieldName release];
    //[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

As you can see, I commented the `[super dealloc];`, which is causing the Bad Exception, but this is obviously not a good solution.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What's a Bad Exception? (Or rather, what would you consider a Good Exception?)

Comment: check wat is throwing bad exception by setting NSZombieEnabled = YES

Comment: [http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/](http://)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties might have never been used, so they haven't been initialized in any way

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    self.editedObject = nil;
    self.editedFieldKey = nil;
    self.editedFieldName = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work, however not sure why, cause the exception happend at at the dealloc and not on the release.